# Insert multiple rows in laravel with json payload

Tags: php, json, laravel-4

I have an angular `post` request going to a laravel controller function inserting into a db. The payload looks like this:

```
[
{"id":1,"utid":"ABC","name":"Introduction","docId":1,"position":1},
{"id":2,"utid":"DEF","name":"Chapter One","docId":1,"position":2},
{"utid":"GHI","name":"asd","docId":1,"position":3}
]
```

How do I extract the inputs and assign them correctly to the database command. I imagine something with `foreach` but I don't know the synthax. Can anyone help me?

```
foreach($topics as $topic => $insert )
        {
            DB::table('topics')->insert(array(
                array(
                    'utid' => Input::json('utid'),
                    'name' => Input::json('name'),
                    'docId' => Input::json('docId'),
                    'position' => Input::json('position')
                )
            ));
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `json_decode` first:

```
$json = '[
    {"id":1,"utid":"ABC","name":"Introduction","docId":1,"position":1},
    {"id":2,"utid":"DEF","name":"Chapter One","docId":1,"position":2},
    {"utid":"GHI","name":"asd","docId":1,"position":3}
]';

$data = json_decode($json);
```

Then you could use `Post::create($data);` to create new entries.

To do that you would also need to setup your model to allow mass assignment for these fields:

`protected $fillable = ['utid', 'name', 'Introduction'];`

You can find more about it in the official Laravel documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment).

Comment: When I do this, I get an error saying `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'utid' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into 'topics' () values ())`

Comment: Well, that means that `utid` is NULL or empty and probably need to be set before you try to create the model.